# How to select following sibling/XML tag using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, lxml

I have an HTML file (from Newegg) and their HTML is organized like below.  All of the data in their specifications table is '*desc*' while the titles of each section are in '*name.*' Below are two examples of data from Newegg pages.

```
<tr>
    <td class="name">Brand</td>
    <td class="desc">Intel</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">Series</td>
    <td class="desc">Core i5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">Cores</td>
    <td class="desc">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">Socket</td>
    <td class="desc">LGA 1156</td>
```

```
<tr>
    <td class="name">Brand</td>
    <td class="desc">AMD</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">Series</td>
    <td class="desc">Phenom II X4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">Cores</td>
    <td class="desc">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">Socket</td>
    <td class="desc">Socket AM3</td>
</tr>
```

In the end I would like to have a class for a CPU (which is already set up) that consists of a Brand, Series, Cores, and Socket type to store each of the data.  This is the only way I can think of to go about doing this:

```
if(parsedDocument.xpath(tr/td[@class="name"])=='Brand'):
    CPU.brand = parsedDocument.xpath(tr/td[@class="name"]/nextsibling?).text
```

And doing this for the rest of the values. How would I accomplish the nextsibling and is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

> How would I accomplish the nextsibling
>   and is there an easier way of doing
>   this?

**You may use**:

```
tr/td[@class='name']/following-sibling::td
```

**but I'd rather use directly**:

```
tr[td[@class='name'] ='Brand']/td[@class='desc']
```

**This assumes that**:

1. The context node, against which the XPath expression is evaluated is the parent of all `tr` elements -- not shown in your question.
2. Each `tr` element has only one `td` with `class` attribute valued `'name'` and only one `td` with `class` attribute valued `'desc'`.

Comment: Note that you have to be careful about using class. When your 'name' class elements have any other class at the same time, `td[@class='name']` will break. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9133579/2197555) for details.

Comment: @gm2008, Yes, in case there is more than one class in the value of the @class attribute, the predicate to use is: `contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), '  name ')`  . But in this question the @class attributes do have only single values.

Comment: Relative to an element: `./following-sibling::td`

Comment: @JohnGietzen, Re: "Relative to an element" -- You mean If the *context node* is the element we are interested in. In this case you can omit `./` . Also, if you want to select the immediate following sibling, use: `following-sibling::td[1]`, otherwise, if there are more than one following siblings, all will be selected.

Answer (score 17):

Try the `following-sibling` axis (`following-sibling::td`).

Answer (score 13):

For completeness - adding to accepted answer above - in case you are interested in **any sibling regardless of the element type** you can use variation:

`following-sibling::*`