# Two elements with same parent element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE to test a tree.

I am having two elements with same parent element, one is a check box and the other is a text.

My question is, can I use the text element to make selenium click on the check box?!

in another way, can I connect the two elements to each others some how?!!

Comment: Can you add the source for parent, checkbox, and text?  That'd make it much easier to help you.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139402/how-to-select-following-sibling-xml-tag-using-xpath

Comment: Can you post some sample brief html?

Answer (score 0):

As for me I am right click on the browser webpage that I want to test. And I can easily chose by show all available command. Note that when you right click on the browser you need to open your `selenium-ide`.

Hope this will helpful.