# Match first table cell, extract the second

Tags: xpath, domxpath, xpath-1.0

I have a table and want to extract data from some data cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="label"> </td>
        <td class="data"><p><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Kang"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/LiuKangshaolinmonks.jpg"/></a></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">First game</td>
        <td class="data">Mortal Kombat (1992)</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="label">Created by</td>
        <td class="data">John Tobias</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="label">Orgin</td>
        <td class="data">Earthrealm</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="label">Weapon</td>
        <td class="data">Nunchaku</td>
    </tr>   
        <tr>
        <td class="label">Colour</td>
        <td class="data">Red</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to extract `Nunchaku`, this works:

```
/html/body//tr[5]/td[@class="data"]
```

But I would rather like to skip `tr[5]` and instead use `td[contains(., 'Weapon')]` but I am unsure how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `following-sibling::`

```
//td[contains(., 'Weapon')]/following-sibling::td
```

Checkout this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139402/how-to-select-following-sibling-xml-tag-using-xpath) or [read some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256456(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information about following-sibling.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative: `/html/body//tr[td[@class = 'label'] = 'Weapon']/td[@class = 'data']`.