# how to find the following node (siblings and preceding) using xpath

Tags: xpath

```
 <months>
  <month name="January"></month>
  <month name="February"></month>
  <month name="March"></month>
  <month name="April"></month>

  ...[etc]

</months>
```

how to get the siblings here from the above code i want the xpath for node after february

I want an XPath expression such that if given programming questions site it will give month after february

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select following sibling/xml tag using xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139402/how-to-select-following-sibling-xml-tag-using-xpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a XPath something like this:

```
//months/month[@name='February']/following-sibling::month
```