# How can I select the xpath parent sibling?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, siblings

If I have this xml structure:

```
<tr>
    <td class="name">
        <b>Brand</b>
    </td>
    <td class="desc">Intel</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">
        <b>Series</b>
    </td>
    <td class="desc">Core i5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">
        <b>Cores</b>
    </td>
    <td class="desc">4</td>
</tr>
```

How can I get the "desc" value when name == Series?

I've followed another example here
[How to select following sibling/xml tag using xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139402/how-to-select-following-sibling-xml-tag-using-xpath)

However, that example did not have the  tags around the "name" value so following-sibling doesn't work at the  level. How do I go back a level to the  level?

Comment: The given text is not XML at all. Voting to close the question.

Comment: my original post says "xml structure". Vote vetoed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the sibling axis for this.

This XPath,

```
string(//tr[normalize-space(td[@class='name'])='Series']/td[@class='desc'])
```

will select

```
Core i5
```

for your XML, as requested.

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware it could be done this way. Does this also handle the <b> tag? I don't see reference to it.

Comment: Yes, it will handle any `b`, `i`, etc automatically because it tests the string value of the element rather than testing text nodes.  See [**Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath) for details.