# XPath: Get next element where parent contains text

Tags: xpath

```
<h3>2.2 Header Text</h3>
<dl>
 <dd>Text 1</dd>
</dl>
```

I have the following html code and i need to get the text between the "dd" element where the h3 tag above it contains the text "2.2".

For now I have tried the following xpath to find the h3 tag that contains this text

```
//h3[contains(text(),'2.2')]
```

but I can't figure out how to get the elements below in order to get the dd element. How could i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
//h3[contains(text(),'2.2')]/following-sibling::dl/dd
```

For more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139402/how-to-select-following-sibling-xml-tag-using-xpath) discussion